# How to colorize upper or lower side of plot in R

Tags: r, plot

let say I have some data and some of them lower than 0, and some of them higher than 0 so in R I want to colorize the upper side of the plot, I mean above the zero line how can I do this ? Thanks.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using `geom_ribbon` from `ggplot2`. For example:

```
library(ggplot2)
df = data.frame(x = 1:10, y = c(runif(5, -1, 0), runif(5, 0, 1)))
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
        geom_ribbon(aes(ymax = 0.6, ymin = 0), fill = "magenta") +
        geom_line()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can group your data based on whether it is >0 or not. Consequently you can provide different colors for these groups.

`db$group <- ifelse(db$variable1>=0,1,0)`

For example for a plot with two variables:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(db, aes(x=variable1, y=variable2, fill=group)) + geom_point()
```

You can also use color instead of fill if you want to change the outline of a point.
For a a histogram you can add geom_histogram instead of geom_point.

Comment: thank you, I was contemplating more complex stuff than this, appreciated.